# Get attribute of inner node in XML

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a next XML file

```xml
<cities>
<country name="Абхазия">
    <city id="37188" region="27028" head="" type="3" country="Абхазия" part="" resort="" climate="">Новый Афон</city>
</country> 
</cities>
```

And i need to get the id attribute from the inner city node. I've done the next code, but i have no idea how to proceed:

```
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml);
        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_COUNTRY);

        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {

            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            String city = parser.getValue(e, KEY_CITY);

        }
```

Comment: XMLPULLPARSER! Use it.

Comment: `Element.getAttribute("id")`? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html#getAttribute%28java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("city");
    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
        String id = nodeList.item(i).getAttributes().getNamedItem("id").getTextContent();
        //  do something with 'id'
        String cityName = nodeList.item(i).getTextContent();
        //  do something with 'cityName'
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, it won't work, i forgot that i have another tag. I edited my post.

Comment: @k.nadonenko I have checked - this code works with the last XML form. What are you trying to get in addition to the ID? From what attribute?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that i need not only the city id, also i need the city name.

Comment: <city id="37188" region="27028" head="" type="3" country="Абхазия" part="" resort="" climate="">Новый Афон</city> Here is the city name "Новый  Афон".

Comment: @k.nadonenko Я думал, что тут подразумевался "Новый аЙфон". )

Answer (score 2):

Use this methord.

```
NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("City");

        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            Node nNode = nl.item(i);
            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

                String id = eElement.getAttribute("id");

            }
        }
```

Comment: Sure it will work.. First you have to get the elements by tag name country tag and get the attribute inside that tag. Inside the inner loop you have to get the elements by tag name city and get its attributes.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++){ 
        Node n = nl.item(i);
        if (n.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            Element e = (Element)n;
            String yourId = e.getAttribute("KEY_CITY");
        }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use XmlPullParser..... here is a [link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidXML/article.html) to a tutorial so u can get started with